# How to change default mouse hover behavior on dynamically generated buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, dynamically-generated, mousehover

I am a relatively new user of WPF and have run into a problem regarding dynamic Button generation and Buttons' default hover properties.

I am currently working on an application where a significant number of buttons are being generated on a Canvas in the code behind. The contents of each button are unique images referenced by an array of objects containing Uri strings. This array is populated by reading in a file containing these Uri strings, so the number and placement of buttons on this canvas vary based on which file is being read.

For the most part, the appearance of the Canvas when the application runs is what was intended, however hovering over any of the Buttons replaces the image with the default blue background for the duration that the mouse overlaps.

Here is an example of the code that I am using to generate the buttons:

```
exampleButton = new Button { Content = "Name", Width = 50, Height = 65, Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@object.UriString, UriKind.Relative))) };
exampleButton.Style = exampleStyle;
exampleCanvas.Children.Add(exampleButton);
```

Please understand that I have omitted pieces of code irrelevant to my question.

Here is an example of the style that was used, also in the code behind:

```
exampleStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
exampleStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent));
exampleStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Transparent));
```

Together these achieve the effect I am trying to create, barring hover behavior.

So far I have tried appending ControlTemplate overrides into the style declaration but am unsure of how that translates from XAML to the C# code behind. I have also tried creating and binding button templates created in the XAML but I haven't had success in finding explanations or tutorials that apply to my situation.

Any help to accomplish this via the code behind would be greatly appreciated. Of course, if I'm doing this really unconventionally and there is a more standard way of doing things I am all ears.

**EDIT:**
This is the XAML I am using to declare the style that my dynamically generated buttons are using.

```
<Style x:Key="MySuperButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="65" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Using this call to assign the style in the code behind:

```
exampleButton.Style = (Style)FindResource("MySuperButtonStyle");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the default `Button` control style has a trigger that changes the `Background` property of the button when the mouse hovers over it. You need to use a custom style for the button:

```
<Style x:Key="MySuperButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="65" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here the width and the height are set using the style, so you no longer need to set those properties in code. The control template has been changed so it consists only of a `Border` element with the content inside of it. There are no triggers at all, so the button won't change its appearance when clicked or hovered over.

In your code all you need to do is obtain a reference to this style then assign that to the `Style` property when you are creating the button.

Having said all this, in WPF you rarely need to create controls in code. Instead you should really be using the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern and data binding. You probably shouldn't be creating styles and setters in code either.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Say I did want to add a trigger, would it look anything like this?

`<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Trigger>

</ControlTemplate.Triggers>`


Nothing seems to be happening when I insert this into the style.

Comment: You want to add triggers like that to the *style's* triggers collection, not the *control template's*. In other words, `<Style.Triggers> <Trigger Property=" ... `. Then in the control template use template bindings to bind to the control properties that you are changing in the style triggers. For example, you might set the border brush property of the `Border` element like so: `<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ...`.

Comment: I have implemented what you have suggested and from what I can tell, the trigger is firing as intended, however the property for BorderBrush is either not actually changing or the change is not being reflected. Even explicitly setting its value in the style declaration isn't doing anything. Is it being overridden by something?

Comment: @RGMGDD Could you edit your question to post the XAML for your style?

Comment: @RGMGDD It's because your `BorderThickness` property is set in the style, but you have not bound that property inside the control template, therefore the `Border` element uses its default thickness of zero. The colour is changing in response to the trigger but you can't see it because the thickness is effectively making the border invisible. Just set the border thickness inside the template like so: `BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"`.

Comment: And with that I am on my way, thank you very much. Onward to learning MVVM.